# Receiving null from childSnapshot.key

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

This is how my database looks like:

```
 -members
 --L_C3OzCYFevhXzT5xk9 (specific key for Chat Room)
 ---user1: 'test@gmail.com'
 ---user2: 'test1@gmail.com'
```

I am trying to receive this specific key from Firebase and set it into the state. This is how I am trying to do that:

```
const query = firebase.database().ref('/members').orderByKey().equalTo(email);
     query.once('value')
     .then(function(snapshot) {
       snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
         var key = childSnapshot.key;
         this.setState({ChatID: key});
       });
     });
     console.log(this.state.ChatID);
```

But every time I receive 'null' in console.log
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The query is asynchronous and returns a promise that resolves some time later.  Your log message is executing before that query finishes.  You can only use the results of the query after the promise resolves and your `then()` callback is invoked.